# How do I flip an image and keep the flipped side on

Tags: html, jquery, css

I want to rotate an image to 180 degrees and keep the flip side on.
I've tried various css but image gets back to its original side when I hover anywhere else.

I'm posting one of the tried code here

CSS :

```
.card {
    width: 130px;
    height: 195px;
    background: url("images/card-back.jpg") no-repeat;
    margin: 50px;
}

.card:hover {
    background: url("images/card-front.jpg") no-repeat;
}
```

HTML :

```
<body>
    <div class="card"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: That's the expected behavior of hover. Try using  an event in JS instead and just remove the event handler after it runs once. This will leave the image rotated and no amount of hovering will return it to normal without a page reload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wanted this result?

```js
$(".card").mouseover(function(){
  $(this).css('transform', 'rotate(180deg)');
})
```

```css
.card {
            width: 130px;
            height: 195px;
            background: url("https://sun9-32.userapi.com/impf/c824201/v824201969/173424/ayWCFmi538s.jpg?size=200x0&quality=90&sign=b461a01af900c4374512c2b13455c25d&ava=1") no-repeat;
            margin: 50px;
            transition: 1s;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="card"></div>
</body>
```